# can X-Y coordinates be used as value containers for more than X-Y coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create a tile based grid and I need to get the X-Y coordinates to hold more values than just the X-Y position to determine characteristics of the tile such as resources (such as in the context of a game, within a tile it might contain food, water, stone, lumber, etc.) for example I will use a 2x2 tile grid:
lets pretend these are the tiles displayed by the canvas

```
(x[1]y[1]),(x[2]y[1])
(x[1]y[2]),(x[2]y[2])
```

and these are the values i want the coordinates to hold

```
(x[1]y[1](contains:10 stone, 15 lumber))
(x[2]y[1](contains:5 food, 2 water))
(x[1]y[2](contains:17 water, 6 food, 10 lumber))
(x[2]y[2](contains:30 stone, 7 lumber))
```

how would I go about getting the coordinates to hold said other values?

If you cant already tell im fairly new to coding and such so please try to make it simple to understand for me. Thanks in advance for any and all help.

### Update!

so with the help of azad I figured out how to create the X-Y coordinates with other values held within them and using objects and a looped function to fill in all the objects with all the information I needed to store within them.

### solution

```
XYinitialize = function(){

    XY = {};
    y = 1;
    x = 0;
    for(i = 0;i < Math.pow(gridsize,2);i++){

        if(x < gridsize){x++}else{x = 0;y++}

        XY['Tile' + i] = {
        'X':x,
        'Y':y
        };
    };
}
```

The grid size is determined by the number of tiles in a single row or col and it creates a single row then moves down to the next row creating the tiles with the X and Y coords and any other values within the tile can be added in as needed. if the grid size is 3 tiles per row the output would look similar to:

XY.Tile0:[object Object]
.X1
.Y1

XY.Tile1:[object Object]
.X2
.Y1

XY.Tile2:[object Object]
.X3
.Y1

XY.Tile3:[object Object]
.X1
.Y2

etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use javascript objects to hold more data,

```
 [ {x:1, y:1, stones:10, food:0, water:0, lumber:15},  {x:2, y:1, stones:0, food:5,water:2, lumber:0},
{x:1, y:2, stones:0, food:6, water:17, lumber:10},  {x:1, y:1, stones:30, food:0, water:0, lumber:7}]
```

Comment: Do I have to manually input each object for every tile in the grid or can i set up a while function to loop the creation of the object until the entire grid is filled with tiles?

Comment: use what method suit your needs